# gulp chown doesn't change owner

Tags: gulp

I am trying to make a build process, sort of, and it seems like gulp-chown doesn't give me the correct results.

This is what I run:

```
gulp.task('clientDeploy', function () {
    return gulp.src('client/dist/**/*')
        .pipe(chown('rf', 'rfids'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('/var/www/html/dashboard'));
});
```

The gulp script runs as root, obviously.

The result is this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 29 12:57 css/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 29 12:57 fonts/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 29 12:57 icons/
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Jun 29 12:57 images/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Jun 29 12:57 js/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 8.3K Jun 29 13:15 events-panel.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  20K Jun 29 13:15 index.html
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 8.2K Jun 29 13:15 main-panel.html
```

I've read [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-chown/issues/5) on GitHub that the problem might be with gulp.dest() that doesn't read the file's metadata, and uses the user that runs the command.

Has anyone ever come across this and solved it?

Comment: do you run gulp with sudo or as root?

Comment: With sudo, it's a part of a larger build system for the whole server

Comment: may be use chown after gulp.dest (swap that two pipes)

Comment: I've tried that too... didn't seem to make any difference

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in `vinyl-fs`. When it writes a file to disk, it honors the `file.stat.mode` (where `file` is a `vinyl` `File` object) but it completely ignores the values of `file.stat.uid` and `file.stat.gid`.

It looks like it has been [fixed](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl-fs/issues/157) in the code base of `vinyl-fs` but AFAIK there is no release yet that contains the fix.

Someone in the bug report you linked to mentions having cloned `gulp-chown` but I don't think that's necessary. I just change the file ownership after `gulp.dest` has done its work:

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import es from "event-stream";
import fs from "fs";

gulp.task("build",
          () => gulp.src("src/**/*")
            .pipe(gulp.dest("build"))
            .pipe(es.map((file, callback) => {
                fs.chown(file.path, file.stat.uid, file.stat.gid,
                         (err) => callback(err, file));
            })));
```

You see I'm just using `file.stat.uid` and `file.stat.gid`. My goal is to *preserve* the ownership that the source file has. (Yeah, because `vinyl-fs` does not even do *this* by default.) You can just put any `uid` and `gid` you want there.

Comment: I have a system that I build and install each time on a different machine, therefore I can't know the user and group id's in advance...
What I use for now is just a bash script that runs after gulp is done, and changes the user and group to the right ones.

Comment: I cannot see what could possibly prevent the `chown` operation performed by your bash script from being done in JavaScript with gulp.